# Strategy.entry quantity (fixed or percent)

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have this strategy in tradingview:

```
strategy("NAME", "SHORT_NAME", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, initial_capital=100, default_qty_value=20, precision=4, currency = currency.USD, pyramiding =5, commission_value = 0.075)
```

I've tryed different options with different results:

```
if (buy)
    strategy.entry(id="BUY", long=true)
```

It works but ignores the default_qty_value and uses all the capital configures in the bot.

```
if (buy)
    strategy.entry(id="BUY", long=true, qty = 20)
```

Doesn't give any errors in Pine Script but the bot (from Quadency) don't receive the alert

```
if (buy)
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long, 10)
```

This is how is written in the Quadency tutorial. Does not work and Pine script give syntax errors

I want the bot to place an order of the 20% of the initial_capital so I can run it with pyramiding 5 orders at a time.

How should I write the strategy.entry?

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © adolgov

//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, initial_capital=100, currency = currency.USD, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=20)

longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
if (shortCondition)
    strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Gives next results:
[image]